# Solving the recurrence $ T[n] = \frac{n}{T[n-1]}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Ive had some experience solving recurrences but i think they have been more simple than this one.  This is what i have so far:
\begin{array}{rcl}T[1] & = & 1 \\
T[n]  & = & \frac{n}{T[n-1]}\\ 
\frac{n}{T[n-1]} & = & \frac {nT[n-2]}{n-1}\\
\frac{nT[n-2]}{n-1} & = & \frac{n^2 -2n}{nT[n-3]-T[n-3]}\end{array}
I could keep going but I don't think it will help.  The Problem I'm finding is finding a general formula for the recurrence; the fact that $T[\_]$ alternates each time is making it hard for me to get any further.

Comment: Just imagine it : $T(n) = \frac{n}{T(n-1)} = \frac{(n!!)^{2}}{n!}$

Comment: I guess you have a mistake in last step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $T_{n+2}=\frac{n+2}{T_{n+1}}=\frac{n+2}{n+1}T_{n}$, $T_{1}=1,T_{2}=2$. So $T_{2n}=\frac{2.4..2n}{1.3..(2n-1)},T_{2n+1}=\frac{1.3..(2n+1)}{2.4..2n}$ You can find a neat way to write this as [Wallis Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)